# Image in ActionMailer Not Working -- Yields Super Long (Content ID-String), Not Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I get a crazy long string as a result of calling the inline attachment...

```
----==_mimepart_53aa76257659d_23ff6bff4b848679f6 Content-Type: image/png; charset=UTF-8; filename=tippedlogods.png Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: inline; filename=tippedlogods.png Content-ID: <53aa762572f79_23ff6bff4b8486782f@c652b828-9c76-4af2-a50c-d1ff3f5c7273.mail> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAwIAAAE2CAYAAAGlzxW8AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0 d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAA2hpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9i ZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2Vo aUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6 bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMy1jMDExIDY2 LjE0NTY2MSwgMjAxMi8wMi8wNi0xNDo1NjoyNyAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpS REYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJk Zi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIg eG1sbnM6eG1wTU09Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9tbS8i IHhtbG5zOnN0UmVmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvc1R5 cGUvUmVzb3VyY2VSZWYjIiB4bWxuczp4bXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5j b20veGFwLzEuMC8iIHhtcE1NOk9yaWdpbmFsRG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRp ZDo5QzUwNkJGNTVCMjM2ODExOEMxNEZBRTQ4MzA2MjI1QiIgeG1wTU06RG9j dW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDo5RENENTgxQkY0MjgxMUUzOTcwQkY4NjIxNDc2
```

It's actually a lot longer than that, and sorry for formatting, I copied it from what the email gave me.

This is how I call the image

```
<%= image_tag attachments['tippedlogods.png'].url %>
```

the mailer

```
  def confirmation(order)
    @order = order
    attachments.inline['tippedlogods.png'] = File.read("app/assets/images/tippedlogods.png")
    mail(to: @order.email, subject: "Order Confirmation", content_type: "text/html")
  end
```

In my production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'hidden-peak-xxxx.heroku.com', :only_path => false}
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'hidden-peak-xxxx.heroku.com'
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address    => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port       => 587,
  :user_name  => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password   => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain     => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN'],
  :authentication  => :plain
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how attachments work under the hood: a delimiter that marks the separation between attachments, a header that has metadata about the attachment (eg its type) and then the actual image data, encoded in some fashion. The content id attribute can be used to reference the attachment from the HTML portion of the email.

For this to work, the overall content type of the email needs to be one of the multipart  ones, however you seem to be forcing it to text/html, which makes mail clients interpret the entire body as one document, instead of recognising it as a succession of separate parts.

If you drop the content_type option from your call to `mail` you should be ok (rails should infer the type of the message part of the email from the filename of the template)